# i am trying to install django-allauth and i am getting below error on mac

Tags: django

I am getting below error. I need help to resolved this.

Using cached django-allauth-0.34.0.tar.gz
Collecting Django>=1.8 (from django-allauth)

Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 

> "<string>"

, line 1, in <module>
    File 

> "/private/var/folders/br/56_l2gp52_d7zcv_tqyf_fkw0000gn/T/pip-`build-IeTRWv/Django/setup.py"`




line 32, in <module>
       version = __import__('django').get_version()
     File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
       from django.utils.version import get_version
     File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
       @functools.lru_cache(

)
`enter code here`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

**----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/br/56_l2gp52_d7zcv_tqyf_fkw0000gn/T/pip-build-IeTRWv/Django/**
```

Comment: Django 1.7.2 has been installed before this error occurred. **pip install django-allauth**  was the command used for the django-allauth installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `django-allauth` version 0.34.0 support `Django` version 2. Try installing `Django` at a lower version number.

It appears that support for `Django` version 2 is in progress but not deployed from some of the commit messages found on https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/ and not https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/0.34.0 (which is the version being installed in your case)

Edit: please not that if you are using python 2 it is not supported by `Django` version 2 refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility.

You may need to install a lower version of `Django` e.g.:

```
pip install "Django<2"
```

Comment: I am using django 1.7.2 when this installation error occurred.

Comment: Please update the question above as it has indicated `Django-2.0` was being used. Can you please also provide the command you are using to install `django-allauth`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem django-allauth version 0.34.0 does not support django version less than Django 2.0. So i have to use python3.6 while i upgrade my project to Django 2.0. and everything is working fine now.